# Could I get help implementing a concept, "When a String changes, its type changes"

Tags: haskell, types

One day on #haskell, someone mentioned the concept of how a string's type should change when the string changes. This reminded me of some code I have in my project. It keeps bugging me, and I couldn't articulate why. The reason, I now surmise, is because I am not implementing this concept. Here's the code below, followed by some ideas of how I can begin to change it for the better. What I would like is some input to the effect of , "You're on the right track." or , "No, way off.", or "Here's this other thing you should be mindful of.".

```
> processHTML :: String -> [[String]]
> processHTML htmlFILE =
>            let parsedHTML        = parseTags htmlFILE
>                allTagOpens       = sections (~== TagOpen "a" [("href","")]) parsedHTML
>                taggedTEXT        = head $ map (filter isTagOpen) allTagOpens
>                allHREFS          = map (fromAttrib "href") taggedTEXT
>                allPotentials     = map (dropWhile (/= '?')) allHREFS
>                removedNulls      = filter (not . null) allPotentials
>                removedQs         = map (drop 1) removedNulls
>            in map (splitOn "&") removedQs
```

The idea here is I'm taking raw HTML and filtering out everything I don't want until I get what I do want. Each let binding represents a stage in filtering. This could be the foundation of a data structure, like so:

```
> data Stage = Stage1 Foo
>            | Stage2 Bar
>            | Stage3 Baz
```

Where Foo Bar and Baz are the appropriate datatype; a String, or TagOpen for example, depending on what stage I am at in the filtering process. I could use this data type to get precise information when I add in the error handling code. Plus, it could help me keep track of what is happening when.

Feedback appreciated.

Comment: Why do you strive for changing type? Also, can you describe what `processHTML` is supposed to do?

Comment: Hmm thought I explained why I wanted to change type. I think it will help me get more precise information during error handling (yet to be implemented). Also, though I am the one who wrote this I have to run these let bindings in ghci to see what is happening. I think I could use types to communicate to myself more information.

Comment: ProcessHTML is capturing data I need from HTML generated via screenscraping, by removing everything that I don't what until what I do want is the only thing left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

First of all, when you're building a long pipeline like this, you may prefer to compose functions directly:

```
> processHTML :: String -> [[String]]
> processHTML =
>            parseTags
>            >>> sections (~== TagOpen "a" [("href","")])
>            >>> head $ map (filter isTagOpen)
>            >>> map (fromAttrib "href")
>            >>> map (dropWhile (/= '?'))
>            >>> filter (not . null)
>            >>> map (drop 1)
>            >>> map (splitOn "&")
```

This uses `Control.Category.(>>>)`, which is just (at least in this case) flipped function composition.

Now for your actual question, it looks like you're using the [tagsoup](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup) package for parsing tags.  This already does some type changing throughout the pipeline: `parseTags` generates a `Tag`, some functions operate on it, and then `fromAttrib` goes back to a String.

Depending on how much work you'll be doing, I might create a newtype:

```
newtype QueryElement = QE { unQE :: String } deriving (Eq, Show)

> processHTML :: String -> [[QueryElement]]
> processHTML =
>            parseTags
>            >>> sections (~== TagOpen "a" [("href","")])
>            >>> head $ map (filter isTagOpen)
>            >>> map (fromAttrib "href")
>            >>> map (dropWhile (/= '?'))
>            >>> filter (not . null)
>            >>> map (drop 1)
>            >>> map (splitOn "&" >>> map QE)
```

Only the last line has changed here, to add the QE newtype tags to each element.

Depending on your use case, you could take a difference approach.  For example, you may want to add more information to the URI instead of just collecting the query variables.  Or you might want to fold over the query items and produce a `Map String String` directly.

Finally, if you're trying to gain type safety, you usually wouldn't make a sum type such as your `Stage`.  This is because each constructor creates a value of the same type, so the compiler can't do any extra checking.  Instead you'd create a separate type for each stage:

```
data Stage1 = Stage1 Foo
data Stage2 = Stage2 Bar
data Stage3 = Stage3 Baz

doStage1 :: Stage1 -> Stage2

doStage2 :: Stage2 -> Stage3
```

It's easy to create very fine-grained classes and data structures, but at some point they get out of hand.  For example, in your functions `allPotentials`, `removedNulls`, and `removedQs`, you may want to just work on Strings.  There isn't a lot of semantic meaning that can be attached to the output of those stages, especially as they're partial steps within a slightly larger process.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2006/10/18/a-type-based-solution-to-the-strings-problem) talks about using types to enforce safety of operations, and causing common errors to show up at compile-time.  I'm not sure, but I think this is along the lines of what you're trying to implement.

An example of the problem:
You're running a web application that needs to use a database.  It generates an SQL query from the username and password (for example) and sends it off to the database server, gets a response, and presents it to the user.  This works great for a while.  But then a very rude user types in `" OR 1 = 1; --` for the username.  Can you imagine sending that string to the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = "$" AND username = "$";
```

Disaster!

The basic solution:
1) create a type for strings that are safe to send to the database server (i.e. GoodSQLString)
2) make sure that all GoodSQLString's really are safe (perhaps the constructor passes the argument query string through an escaping function)
3) only allow GoodSQLString's to be sent to the database server from an application

That said, it's hard to say how that translates to your `processHTML` problem.  Perhaps the type signature should be `processHTML :: HTML -> [Tags]` -- unless it's meaningful to pass in String's that are invalid HTML.